# How can I count points from several buffer distances in PostGIS updating the table?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point-in-polygon

I have a problem regarding a calulation on PostGIS. I have to calculate how many facilities fall within a given distance. This is not really a problem though, but updating my table is.

I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT buffer1.id, COUNT(facility1) as bf1
FROM buffer1 LEFT JOIN facility1
ON ST_CONTAINS(buffer1.st_buffer,facility.geom)
GROUP BY buffer1.id
```

Now I have to do this again (35 times), so I thought to update the table by entering:

```
UPDATE my_table SET buffer2 FROM(
    SELECT /*the count statement*/) as buffer2
```

But this won't work.

I managed to get a extra column with the Alter Table statement, but it was empty.

I'm able to this manually, but it is easier to this in 1 query, instead of rewriting 36 queries.

Comment: Can you please give more information about your data? did I understood you right that you have 36 facility tables?

Comment: Yes it's unclear.  Do you have 35 distance columns to update?  and why is my question.  I would think it better to store as separate rows in that case rather than columns.

Comment: Please give example of two of these queries at least. So far it looks like you're overwriting all the data in each update.

Comment: Dear all, maybe it's a bit unclear. 

I have 4 buffers tables and 9 facilities tables. What I have to do, is count the ammount of points in the buffer polygon. The Facilities are pointdata. What I want is a output table with the ID of the buffer (which are present in all the buffer tables) and the counts of all the buffers and facilities. 

So something like this:
ID, buffer1facility1, buffer2facility1, buffer3facility1,buffer4facility1,buffer1facility2,etc.

Comment: Does the deferents facilities table have similar column? Same question for buffers table?

Comment: The buffer tables have the same ids. The facilities have just a GID. 

Although I got it working (see the answer). Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by entering this query:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT buffer1.id, COUNT(facility1) as bf1
FROM buffer1 LEFT JOIN facility1
ON ST_CONTAINS(buffer1.st_buffer,facility.geom)
GROUP BY buffer1.id
NATURAL JOIN
SELECT buffer2.id, COUNT(facility1) as bf2
FROM buffer2 LEFT JOIN facility1
ON ST_CONTAINS(buffer2.st_buffer,facility.geom)
GROUP BY buffer2.id
NATURAL JOIN
etc.
```

Quite easy solution and it worked. Thank you for your assistance.